# Embedding images on mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki

I have tried to embed an image on mediawiki that I have installed on my server. The images are in this folder `/var/www/html/mywiki/images$`.
Here is the screenshot of what I see when I save the page to view the image[image]

When I try the upload option, this is the error message i get
`[b5f5e4d3] 2016-10-25 12:30:15: Fatal exception of type "MWException"`
Where could i be making the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience with mediawiki, when you upload to the site it stores them in randomzed lettered/numbered folders... ie w/images/9/9d and you have no control over uploading them directly to the folder through your server. I haven't tried directly uploading them, I've always used the wiki itself to upload.

MediaWiki offers some extensions for bulk uploading here:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Category:Bulk_upload

And you can find them under Special categories once you've installed the Extension and updated your LocalSettings.php to allow them to run.

I personally use BatchUpload (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SimpleBatchUpload) because I don't have a lot of files to upload at one time, and although it is marked as stable, it sometimes sticks... still better than uploading one at a time.

If you find an alternative way for mass uploading using FTP directly to the server, I would love to know... as I searched for that myself.

Good luck!

Comment: You can use https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:ImportImages.php maintenance script to bulk import manually uploaded images (eg. via FTP), though you will neeed SSH access to run it.

Answer (score 1):

You should not upload images manually, but use Special:Upload page to upload image into Mediawiki. Error you've mentioned indicates that there is something wrong with your installation, so you should put `$wgShowExceptionDetails = true;` into `LocalSettings.php` to see more details about this error. There is a chance that your `/images/` directory is not writable - check its permissions.

Comment: at least this give me a stack trace . the `/images/` directory has images already in use so I still don't understand why it can't render the above image. I will still check out for its permissions

Comment: can you please share a stack trace ?